# popup window close issue in case of multiple popups in Edge browser

Tags: javascript, popup, microsoft-edge

This issue only happens in Edge, but works in IE11 and Chrome. Is there a way to get around this?

1. Main window opens a 1st  child window  (Javascript `window.open` when end user clicks a link in the main window)
2. Then when end user clicks a button in the 1st child window, JS will close this 1st child window.
3. Then JS code has the main window opening a 2nd child window  via JS code (`1st_child_window.opener.open`)
4. If end user tries to close this 2nd child window (either a button calling JS `window.close` or browser-provided-“X”-button) it works intermittently. Many times it can’t be closed and remains as blank popup window . It then can only be killed by “task manager”
5. If step #2 is commented out, (that is, leaving the 1st child window open,) the step #4 can work properly (that is, 2nd child window then can be closed properly)

Code listing for step#2 and step#3

```
function showSecondChildScreen(url, FirstChildWindow) {
....
    var mainWindow = FirstChildWindow.opener;
    FirstChildWindow.close();
    var SecondChildScreen =   mainWindow.open(url,'passWin','width=700,top=120,left=200,titlebar=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
....
}
```

**Edit: Code Listing for a small example to reproduce** 
1. html page for the main window

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Popup Window Test
    </title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showFirstChildWindow() {
            var pidWin = window.open("firstChild.html",'firstChild','width=600,height=475,screenX=200,screenY=300,top=220,left=200,titlebar=yes,resizable=yes');
            if (pidWin != null) {
                pidWin.focus();
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<p>
    <b>Main Window </b>
</p>

<a href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="showFirstChildWindow();" > Nurse Patti </a>
</body>
</html>
```

2. html page for the 1st child window

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html> 
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>
       First child
   </title>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   function showSecondChildScreen(url, FirstChildWindow) {

       var mainWindow = FirstChildWindow.opener;
       FirstChildWindow.close();
       var SecondChildScreen =   mainWindow.open(url,'passWin','width=700,top=120,left=200,titlebar=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');

       if (SecondChildScreen != null) {
           SecondChildScreen.focus();
       }

   }
   </script>

   </head>

   <body>
   <p>
   <b>First Child Popup Window </b>
   </p>
   ```
3. html page for the 2nd child window

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html> 
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>
       Second child
   </title>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   function doClose() {    
       window.close();
   }
   </script>

   </head>
   <body>
   <p>
   <b>Second Child Popup Window </b>
   </p>

   <input type="button" value="Close"  onclick="doClose();" />

   </body>    
   </html>
   ```

Steps to reproduce (Also I turned off the "popup blocker" in Edge to make testing easier):

1. Please put above 3 html under the same folder
2. The 1st html page is the Main window. Please open it with Edge browser
3. Clicking “Nurse Patti” will bring up the 1st child popup window
4. End user clicks the “2nd child” button in the 1st child popup window. Then the 1st popup closes. The 2nd child popup opens
5. Either click “close” button or browser-provided-X-button in the 2nd popup. It may or may not close properly. Sometimes this 2nd child becomes a blank one, and only “task manager” can kill it.

Comment: I think you may need to ask Microsoft - Edge does seem to still contain some odd anomalies, indeed, sometimes not work even.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I posted the question on microsoft msdn too. Hope they will get back. Thanks again!

Comment: Good - I had a similar problem about a year ago - windows opened behind existing windows. I thought they'd sorted these issues, but maybe not - it does remain a very new browser...

Comment: I work on the Edge team; can you setup a small repro?

Comment: @Sampson Please see "Edit" in the original post. Thanks! Sorry I will be out of the country for a couple of weeks starting tomorrow, and will not be able to check for a while. Thanks so much  for your help!

Comment: @riceball Thanks; I'll take a look. Safe travels!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up with a different approach -- which is to rewrite those physical popup windows into jQuery popups. Thanks for all the people who helped here.